# Change the font colour of validation error messages in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can we change the font colour of validation error messages in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the documentation, you can change the delimiters applied to form validation errors, like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

So, basically, all your errors will now be wrapped in a `<div>` with the CSS class 'error'. Now, in your CSS, just define:

```
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

More info: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters

Comment: Thanks Rohan..Where i add the set_error_delimiters(In controller or view)?

Comment: The controller, where you set all the other validation rules. The view is only for echoing the error messages, if any.

Comment: But it doesn't work..i added the set_error_delimiters in controller and css in the view